# How can i merge hundreds or even thousands of video files into one using ffmpeg or any other tools?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, concatenation

Basically i have like hundreds of small video files (format is .ts) and each of them is like only 10 seconds long and about 10MB size. They are named in order like '100.ts' '101.ts' '102.ts' ... '600.ts' (names usually dont start from 1), so how can i merge them into 1 big file (and transfer it to mp4 format hopefully as well) using ffmpeg or any other tools? oh also i need to do that in Windows environment, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the `concat` input format:

First create a text file like

```
file "100.ts"
file "101.ts"
...
```

and save it as "merge.ffconcat".

Now use `ffmpeg -f concat -i "merge.ffconcat" [your codec options here] -f mp4 output.mp4` to merge and if necessary reencode.